# How to check if one of several elements exists?

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

How to check if one of elements exists?

I know there is a function `assertExists`, but it only checks for one specific element. I need to check whether one of three elements exists on a page (for example I have a login link which is of different class for different sites, but normally I can group these sites in three categories). Is there any 'and/or' conditions that can be inserted in `assertExists`?

Comment: Thanks for quick response Artjom. That was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have like always with CasperJS multiple ways to achieve this.

The most versatile way is to use [`casper.exists`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exists):

```
test.assert(casper.exists("selector1") || casper.exists("selector2")); // 1
test.assert(casper.exists("selector1") && casper.exists("selector2")); // 2
```

Then you could use `,` to concatenate two CSS selectors or `|` for two XPath expressions, which makes both an OR operation

```
test.assertExists("selector1, selector2");
test.assertExists(x("selector1 | selector2"));
```

If you want an AND operator between the selectors, you can just break this into two statements, because you're testing and one of them will fail:

```
test.assertExists("selector1");
test.assertExists("selector2");
```

I used only two selectors, but this also works the same way for 3 or more selectors.

Comment: works good for assertExists. Is there analogy for assertResourceExists? I tried test.assertResourceExists('site-logo.png, logo'); but looks that it checks whether both resources exist, but not one of them

Comment: use a function instead of a string: `test.assertResourceExists(function check(res){return res.indexOf('site-logo.png') !== -1 || res.indexOf('logo') !== -1});`